# Cannot build VB6 project referencing .net assembly with a 2 digit version number

Tags: .net, vb6, versioning

We have a legacy VB6 project with references a .net assembly like this, note the 1.9 version number;

```
Reference=*\G{guid}#1.9#0#C:\path_to_file.tlb#assmembly_name
                    ^^^
```

Now we're wanting to increment our version number to 1.10 but when updating the reference to;

```
Reference=*\G{guid}#1.10#0#C:\path_to_file.tlb#assmembly_name
```

The project will no longer build and we get a compilation error at the line with the Type from this .net assembly is being used.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: How is the reference to the 1.10 version being set? Are you letting VB6 automatically update it? Or manually selecting it from the References dialog? Or manually editing the VBP?

Comment: The version is set by manually editing the VBP. I've just tried and Visual Basic doesn't even add the reference if I try, it doesn't error just closes the dialog like it has added it but doesn't actually change the VBP.

Comment: You did generate a new `.tlb` file against the v1.10 .NET assembly and registered it on your pc?

Comment: You should not be manually editing this. Try to create a new project and try adding a reference and see if that helps

Comment: @pfx - yes to creating a new tlb, no to registering on the pc, did you mean with regasm? I'll try that tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @TarunLalwani - we have to manually edit the project file to automate the build, unless you know of a way to update the references automatically without modifying the project file? I create an example app tomorrow and post it to show the problem. I suspect it's not possible but we'll see.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Indeed, via regasm, tlbexp doesn’t handle the registration; see steps at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx

Comment: I think you'd need to give a lot more details on your build process, if you're manually editing VB's files and running compilers rather than just using the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any documentation to back this up but I've tested it and it works.

The problem here was that we we're putting the version number in the VB project in base10, where it should be base16. So

```
Reference=*\G{guid}#1.10#0#C:\path_to_file.tlb#assmembly_name
```

actually tries to load version 1.16. To correct this the reference should be

```
Reference=*\G{guid}#1.a#0#C:\path_to_file.tlb#assmembly_name
```

Comment: Good investigating!

Comment: @DaveInCaz, thanks - I'm relieved I found the answer, I thought there might not be one and would have to rethink our versioning.